# Tweepy Bot keeps crashing

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm following this tutorial -
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dvAurfBB6Jk&t=950s

And after the 15:30 mark, I ran my code and it shows an error msg and instantly closes. I cant see what the error is since it closes too fast.           Any help is appreciated!

````
import webbrowser
import time

consumer_key = '[my key]'


consumer_secret = '[my secret Uwu]'

callback_uri = 'oob'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret, callback_uri)
redirect_url = auth.get_authorization_url()
print(redirect_url)
webbrowser.open(redirect_url)

user_pin = input("what the pin? ")
auth.get_access_token(user_pin)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
me = api.me()
print(me.screen_name)```
````

Comment: Do you mind adding the error output to your question so we can see what the exact error is?

Comment: I enter the pin and it instantly closes, I cant really see the error message.